# Getting 'firestore/permission-denied' while integrating firestore in React native mobile app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to firestore documents through react native app, but facing the following issue

Here is the code

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('todos');
  }
```

and we are triggering button click

```
addTodo() {
      this.ref.add({
        title: this.state.textInput,
        complete: false,
      });
    }
```

we are facing this issue

Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).
Error: Firestore: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. (firestore/permission-denied).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If this error occurs when you run `addTodo()` it means that the user doesn't have permission to write to the `todos` collection. Access to Firestore data is controlled through its [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview).

To simply allow anyone to write to `todos` use a rule such as this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But I highly recommend you read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) so that you can write more secure rules that match the needs of your app.

Answer (score 1):

In firestore, if you got any permission denied.This because firestore security rules.

In this case , Goto your database rules section and change **if false** into **if true**

`allow read, write: if true;`